# how to connect docupilot pdf to docusign signature processing

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect, docusign-sdk

I am getting empty space in DocuSign generating an envelope
I want an e-signature on each envelope Id's
I am implementing the PDF using Docupilot and posting it into Docusign using Connect.I got a proper DocuSign mail with an e-sign. But, using the API trigger I can't get an e-sign-in generated PDF.
I want e-sign in all generated PDF using the API trigger

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you mean you want the signed document in the trigger for Connect?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you add a signature field in Docupilot or you add the anchor text to signal a signature field inside the base document.

An example of anchor text may be \s1\

Regards
Adrian
DocuSign Support